# We need a good 3D development software for Linux

Tags: linux, modeling, game-development

Our company is making a game we a few requirements for the thing we want to develop it in.

1. It has to run natively on Linux (no virtual box or Wine)
2. Preferably open source
3. Good support for Blender exports
4. Uses any of these languages: C#, Java, Javascript, Python, Lua
5. Can allow for generating terrain (being able edit a planes vertices)
6. Being able to modify meshes of NPCs
7. Allows for a GUI (ingame menus/HUD)

Comment: Any reason not just using Blender? I haven't used it for game making (just models for export to TES Morrowind/Oblivion), but I believe it can be a full game engine as well.

Comment: @NickWilde no, in terms of being ready for production, the BGE (Blender Game Engine) unfortunately simply isn't up to par. While the Python API of the rest of Blender has seen a massive overhaul with 2.5, the BGE code has hardly been touched and its API is just horrible. Deployment and packaging is also a mere afterthought, at its current stage it's only really useful for prototyping in my opinion. Nowhere near as solid as the rest of Blender's applications (modelling, animation, compositing, ...).

Comment: That being said, I'm really not sure what exactly the OP is looking for. *"3D development software"*? Blender covers all those points except creating GUIs, and most of these are addressed by modeling tools, not game engines as such.